# SQL Server 2000 Backup fails with Status = 33

Tags: sql-server, backup

I am trying to take a Full Backup of a database size about 75GB.

It is `SQL Server 2000 - 8.00.2055 x86`  version. I have plenty of disk space where the backup is being created. So disk space isn't an issue.

The backup process starts fine but half way through it errors out just saying `with status = 33`.

[image]

I have looked into the Error Log and  it is showing the error command the Enterprise Manager executed to take the backup with exactly the same error message, Status 33, which doesn't really help :S

I have been looking for any information online but couldn't find anything....  Any suggestions any solutions any pointers in the direct direction is much appreciated.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Further investigation and "Googling" solved the issue, The issue was with drive, It was compressed and SQL Server did not like that.

### Solution

Removed the compression from Drive and this time backup completed without any errors and much faster.

Answer (score 0):

the error number looks like a [system error](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx): `The process cannot access the file because another process has locked a portion of the file.`.
usual solution is to exclude db and backup files from antivirus scanning.
also verify disk status; that message may sometimes happen when disk is failing and a disk check is a good idea if you have any doubt ^^

Comment: it throws this error when almost 60% of the backup is done. If it was an issue with access to file it would throw this error as soon as the backup process starts.

Comment: i propose a lock issue and not an access issue; moreover the message explicitly refers to a portion of the file and not the whole file. if the backup is not started the file does not exist so no lock can be in place neither on the whole file nor on part of the file. the lock is put after the backup is started. anyway is a very quick check; exclude that folder from AV scanning and give it a try.

Comment: also check if the [destination folder is compressed](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/psssql/archive/2012/07/25/how-it-works-sql-server-bcp-database-i-o-backup-restore-reports-operating-system-error-665-1450-or-33-when-writing-to-the-file-big-data.aspx) (the link refers to sql 2005 on but the problem is the same for sql 2000). error 33 is frequently related to that setting that is not supported.